# How to jump to the outer cursor for loop by considering the results of the inner for loop in PLSQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I am having two 'for loops' for a transaction sequence and one is an 'inner for loop' and the outer one is a cursor for loop. I want to iterate through the transactions using the outer for loop. It will go through the 'inner for loop' for validation checking. If there is any transaction that fails within the inner for loop while validating, it should get removed from my cursor in the first for loop and the next iteration in the outer loop should start the flow. Eg:

```
Begin

    FOR rec in Cur_L1 LOOP
        FOR L_2 LOOP
            --validation checking
        END LOOP;

        --if the validation for the current transaction fails in L_2 it should get removed from the cursor in the first loop and should jump to the next iteration. 
        If the validation part does not give any error below code should be executed.
        .......
        .......
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I tried using a Boolean variable and the 'CONTINUE' keyword in the inner for loop. But it failed as the inner for loop executes until the loop ends and then goes to the code in the first for loop. Is there any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `EXIT`. It's poorly named, I know, but `EXIT` in PL/SQL will break out of a loop just like "`BREAK`" does in many other languages.  Then you can use `CONTINUE` in the outer loop to short-circuit the rest of the loop content and move to the next iteration.